# How to publish an App in elementary (Loki) AppCenter

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I wanted to check if there is some documentation on how to make an App available in the elementary (Loki) App Center.

I have gathered that the application needs to be on GitHub and some hooks needs to be set up to link the GitHub repository for the app into Houston to build the app, have it reviewed and get it published on App Center.

I have developed an app (Nutty) and build it on Launchpad (https://launchpad.net/nutty) which also hosts the ppa for users to install the app. I have now created a repository on GitHub for Nutty - https://github.com/babluboy/nutty

Need some help in how to hook the app into Houston.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Blake Kostner (Houston developer):

> Sorry to say Houston is not ready for prime time yet. The current development focus is the store, and everything needed for the Loki release. We will make an announcement once Houston is released though.