# How to publish on elementary os app center

Tags: development, appcenter, games

I have made a game together with my friends and we thought I'd be great to have it on the elementary app store. How would you go about making that happen? Publish it to the official Ubuntu repositories seems a little bit too complicated and overkill since we only want elementary really. Any ideas? Preferably, we'd not publish it to a PPA and have people install it that way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/how-to-publish-an-app-in-elementary-loki-appcenter).

I gather app publishing on App Center will be done through [Houston](https://github.com/elementary/houston), which is currently still under development.

Blake Kostner, the Houston developer, states:

> Sorry to say Houston is not ready for prime time yet. The current development focus is the store, and everything needed for the Loki release. We will make an announcement once Houston is released though.